# How to get a list of directories in a zip?

Tags: linux, bash, zip, unzip

I am looking for a way to list the directories in a zip file in bash under Linux. I found out there is an application called `zipinfo`, which can list the paths in the zip (without any extra noise to have to parse through (`zipinfo -1 foo.zip`), as opposed to `unzip -l foo.zip`). However, this isn't good enough and I am wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: why `zipinfo -1 foo.zip` is not good enough?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

To list only directories:

```
unzip -l foo.zip "*/"
```

Output (e.g.):

```
Archive:  foo.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  2015-09-10 20:10   work/
        0  2015-08-31 10:45   work/test1/
        0  2015-08-31 10:50   work/test1/cc/
        0  2015-08-31 10:45   work/test1/dd/
        0  2015-08-31 10:45   work/test1/aa/
        0  2015-08-31 10:45   work/test1/bb/
        0  2015-09-09 21:17   work/tmp/
        0  2015-08-23 18:49   work/tmp/work/
        0  2015-09-08 19:33   work/tmp/work/loop/
        0  2015-08-15 16:00   work/tmp/work/1/
        0  2015-08-15 16:00   work/1/
        0  2015-08-24 18:40   work/dir/
        0  2015-09-05 18:07   work/rename/
---------                     -------
        0                     13 files
```

or use

```
zipinfo -1 foo.zip "*/"
```

Output (e.g.):

```
work/
work/test1/
work/test1/cc/
work/test1/dd/
work/test1/aa/
work/test1/bb/
work/tmp/
work/tmp/work/
work/tmp/work/loop/
work/tmp/work/1/
work/1/
work/dir/
work/rename/
```

Comment: `zipinfo -1 foo.zip "*/"` worked best, thank you! :)

Comment: I get `caution: filename not matched:  */` although there are plenty of directories in my zip file. EDIT: Is a zip file expected to contain dedicated directory entries? My file only contains file entries...

Comment: @moi: I recommend to start a new question.

Comment: Neither `unzip -l foo.zip "*/"` nor `zipinfo -1 foo.zip "*/"`are reliable solutions: the Zip file may have been created without dedicated directory entries. For instance the `zip` tool has the option `-D   do not add directory entries`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try piping `unzip -l` to `awk` like this:

```
unzip -l foo.zip | awk '/\/$/ { print $NF }'
```

All the directories in the `unzip -l` output end with a slash and `$NF` prints just the directory path.

Answer (score 1):

#### On Cygwin

I coudn't get either of these to work on my Cygwin. For my immediate use, where I only needed to get one directory deep:

```sh
zipinfo -1 foo.zip | grep -o "^[^/]\+[/]" | sort -u
```

For other directories, you could use `xargs` in combination with some other parsing thing, something like:

```
## PSEUDOCODE
$ zipinfo -1 foo.zip | \
# from the pipe, run 
xargs \
# do something like the following while loop, going one file at a time
while there is still a '/' in the line; do
  parse off "[^/]+([/]|)$" from the line
  print out the new line
done | \
sort -u
```

---

#### System Info

```sh
$ uname -a
CYGWIN_NT-10.0 C-D-ENG-E-INT3 2.11.2(0.329/5/3) 2018-11-08 14:34 x86_64 Cygwin

$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.12(3)-release (x86_64-unknown-cygwin)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

$ systeminfo | sed -n 's/^OS\ *//p'
Name:                   Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise
Version:                10.0.17134 N/A Build 17134
Manufacturer:           Microsoft Corporation
Configuration:          Member Workstation
Build Type:             Multiprocessor Free

$
```

Answer (score 1):

The open-source [Zip_Dir_List](https://github.com/zertovitch/zip-ada/blob/master/tools/zip_dir_list.adb) tool will list all directories for you, even for Zip archives that don't have explicit directory entries. From the link, go up to the repository and follow the build instructions in readme.txt .